# display number of rows with certain value in gridview asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, gridview, webforms

I used the following code to display the total number of rows in gridview

```
Label1.Text = "Total Number of Rows: " + e.AffectedRows.ToString();
```

Now I have a column [NewColumn] with two values, "Yes" and "Null", how can I know the number of rows with the value "YES", and display as "The Number of YES rows: [rows with YES]/[total rows]"?

Comment: Can you provide the markup of your gridview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the RowDataBound event for that. In there check the column `NewColumn` for the correct value and increment the totals.

```
int totalRowsWithYes = 0;

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //cast the row back to a datarowview
        DataRowView row = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

        //check the column value and increment
        if (row["NewColumn"].ToString() == "YES")
        {
            totalRowsWithYes++;
        }
    }
}
```